# Entropy and Gibbs Free Energy of Chelate Complexes

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, coordination-compounds, entropy, free-energy

Of [Cd(NH2CH3)4]2+ and [Cd(en)2]2+ the stability of the latter is higher than the former attributing to chelation in the en complex .This is evident from the fact that the Gibbs Free Energy change for the latter is -60.7kJ/mol-1 whereas for the former it is -37.2 kJ/mol-1.

But the T*deltaS do not all provide any correlation between the stability and the entropy values as the values are -20.1kJ/mol-1 and 4.2kJ/mol-1 respectively . If the second complex has a positive entropy implying lesser stability and more randomness why do we agree on to the Gibbs value that confers stability to the second complex?

Does positive entropy changes not imply greater randomness and hence lesser stability?

Comment: Review proper units and values for entropy, unless you mean the $T \Delta S$ term of the $\Delta G$, which is not entropy.

Comment: Do not think of entropy as randomness in the way you suggest,  instead think about it as the number of configurations and energy levels that can be accessed by a molecule.

Comment: @Poutnik Yes,I corrected it. Now how should I proceed?

Comment: @porphyrin Had my interpretation of entropy been correct I woudn't have posted this question. Could you provide me link to text material that could be helpful?

Comment: have a look at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Therm/entrop.html#e3 for a start. A good phys. chem. textbook or a textbook on statistical mechanics should explain the statistical basis for entropy in a lot more detail as well as the thermodynamic one.

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks! I will go through it.